# Bootstrap DatePicker me obliga a usar Hora, minutos y segundos

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, datepicker, datetimepicker

Tengo este `datepicker` de `bootstrap`, no entiendo porque no me deja utilizar la fecha común, solo `date`, nada de `datetime` porque no necesito la hora...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var date_input = $('input[name="FechaInicio"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options = {
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'top',
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="FechaInicio" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input asp-for="FechaInicio" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="FechaInicio" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ese es mi código, y lo que recibo es que apenas entro a la vista ya está precargado con horas y minutos, y no me deja cargar solo la fecha. Alguna solución?

Soy muy novato con `javascript` así que quizás se me pasa algo...

Mi modelo `C#`:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de inicio")]
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
```

Acá se ve en la vista como viene el modelo precargado...

[image]

Comment: Por lo que veo es que no está funcionando tu date_input.datepicker porque sospecho que $("input[..) no funciona veridica si realmente te trrarbel input o de lo contrario hazlo por nombre de la clase. Mi sospecha es porque seteas yyy/mm/dd pero te muestra dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Hola! como verifico que no funciona ? desde el debug en tiempo de ejecución con F12 ? me salta un error ahi del datetimepicker... pero no se como hacerlo andar

Comment: Al input añadele una clase CSS , por decir Fecha. Input class="form-control fecha"> y en el script haces date_input=$(".fecha")

Comment: Ahora estás el datepicker bootstrap va entrar en conflicto con el formatstring del asp. Debes usar uno u otro.

Comment: Quitarle la opción container al options

Comment: Ya le quite la opcion Container y nada... las direcciones de bootstrap y jquery las tome de una respuesta aqui mismo a una pregunta similar... ahora pruebo con el CSS

Comment: Creo que también las versiones de jquery bootstrap no son correctas. Lo utilice para una página. Mañana temprano te envío el ejemplo de cómo lo hice.

Comment: Dale muchisimas gracias @JuanCarlosGuibovich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mejor utiliza bootstrap-datepicker. Reemplazamos:

```
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" integrity="sha256-6y4q3Cui535VG+TapOjQwXKsxgXP+hfcld77yOd/fac=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"/> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitterbootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"/> 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" integrity="sha256-ncetQ5WcFxZU3YIwggfwOwmewLVX4SHLBtDYnrsxooY=" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" integrity="sha256-K5G+7qV0tjuHL0LlhCU0TqQKR+7QwT8MfEUe2UgpmRY=" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Al input dale un id:

```
   <input id="FechaInicio" asp-for="FechaInicio" placeholder="yyyy/MM/dd" class="form-control" />
```

y con jquery configuramos:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     // Defaults

    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = "es";
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;


    $('#FechaInicio').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });

    });
```

EDICION:

Habría que igualar el id con el name:

La FechaInicio la definí como:

```
    public string FechaInicio { get; set; }
```

y en en controlador en Index() la inicializaba de la siguiente forma:

```
      var fi = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
      ViewData["FechaInicio"] = fi;
```

El ViewData["FechaInicio"] le pone el valor en la vista. Este campo lo convertía en DateTime al momento de buscar los entitys.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, es como si la vista trajera precargado un formato... sigue exactamente igual que antes

Comment: Quitarle el DisplayFormat(DataFormatString en el modelo. Eso está haciendo conflicto.

Comment: Mi campo fecha en el modelo lo puse tipo String

Comment: Ya esta solucionado! con viewmodel y tratando como strings a las fechas... tenias razon! el datetime del model me molestaba! mil gracias amigo!

Comment: Ok  gusto saber que te pude ayudar. Feliz Año.!

Answer (score 4):

Lo único que debes hacer es agregar `format: "YYYY-MM-DD",` dentro de `datetimepicker`, así:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No produjo ningun cambio, gracias por tu respuesta igual!